# WIndows taskbar hidden when WinForms's FormBorderStyle is set to other than Sizable

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, taskbar, formborderstyle

I have a question related to how does the FormBorderStyle property works. When I set the property to Sizable, the Windows taskbar shows perfectly, but when I set it to other than that (e.g. FixedSingle, FixedDialog, etc.), the taskbar doesn't show, it is hidden behind the WinForms application. How can I set the FormBorderStyle to other than Sizable and still be able to see the taskbar?

EDIT: What I mean by the taskbar is the Windows taskbar, on which the applications are shown. This is an example with the FormBorderStyle set to Sizable:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2em8g.png). As you can see, when you move the mouse to the bottom of the screen, the Windows taskbar shows.
In contrast, when I set the property to, for example, FixedSingle, this is what happens: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3izxP.png). The taskbar doesn't show.

Comment: Are you sure that the  from's `ShowInTaskbar` property is set to `true`?

Comment: Are you referring to the "chrome" of the window (minimize, maximize buttons etc) or the element in the Task bar? You say "anything other than that", but what are you setting it to? Post a sample of your code.

Comment: For a borderless Form, you need to assign the size of the screen's working area to the `Form.MaximumSize` property. Add in the `Form.Load` event handler this line: `this.MaximumSize = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Size;` and try.

Comment: It is specific to FormBorderStyle = None, the OS then allows the window to overlap the taskbar when it gets maximized.  Fixing this requires intercepting WM_GETMINMAXINFO to limit the window to the Screen.WorkingArea, example is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37206018/17034).